# Force to run cached HTML pages

Tags: html, caching

I have several html-php pages running on the server.

I use the ff. to traverse and loop around the pages

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=../page2.html" />
```

However, I have several client side stations requesting for the pages everytime.

Can I force their IE9 to load cached pages instead to prevent them to request for the pages again from the server.

Note: I successfully loaded the pages from the client side after I loaded the pages first time and turned off the network connection. However the pages only loads properly when I directly enter the URL (e.g. "http://site.page1.html") but when the

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=../page2.html" />
```

kicks in, the browser cannot load the page anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When client request a page from the browser it will check some conditions with a set of rules and if they pass it will load page from the cache otherwise it will request the page from the server but in your page you explicitly say browser that `please refresh your page after 5 seconds` and now you say how should I ask him to not refresh content?
However you can respond from the server that my content is still up to date using status code `304` and then browser is allowed to load its cached version again!